# How to "connect" multiple formulas/variables between them in python

Tags: python, math, circular-reference

Suppose I have 2 variables which were valorised by user input.
With these 2 values, through a formula, i find the third value

So i've got:

```
value_a = x
value_b = y
value_c = z # found doing value_a/value_b
```

Now user want to change one of the values, let's say the one I found with my previous formula (value_c)

How can I do this without rewriting the inverse forumula?
With 3 variables it is not an issue but consider I have more than 10 user imputs + 15 more variables automatically calculated, and in some ways they are all correlated.
How can I avoid to write every possible path?

Comment: I recommend looking into [module `sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html). For instance: `import sympy; a,b,c = sympy.symbols('a b c'); print( sympy.solve(a / b - c), 'b')` will print `[a/c]`

Comment: In the example that you stated, how do you determine which variables would change when you change `value_c`? If  `value_c` changes, either `value_a` or `value_b` or both would have to change to keep the relation intact.
For your equation, you need to determine the independent and dependent variables.

Comment: `sympy.solve(a/b -c, [b])` will give you `a/c` assuming `b` is allowed to change. Similarly `sympy.solve(a/b -c, [a])` will give you `b*c` assuming `a` is allowed to change.